# Netbeans start up is become slower more and more

Tags: netbeans, startup, netbeans-6.9

I am using *netbeans 6.9.1* with the *latest JDK* version on *Windows 7*. 
I deactivated all unnecessary plug-ins.

But as time pass, netbeans start up is becoming slower and slower.
I deleted cache folder of netbeans but seems it can not help.

*What else can I do?*

Comment: How many projects do you have open when it starts?

Comment: You can search the net for 'netbeans startup optimisation'. I know this looks like a stupid easy comment, but i felt like reading 'my computer goes slow; what can i do?' Somehow, read this : http://wiki.netbeans.org/StartupCache.